# Fullscreen script that resize 3 div's evenly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize

I have 3 divs, and i want to write fullscreen script, so when I press some button it resizes 3 divs evenly. How can I do this? Maybe there are something likes this on the net, just can't find this ...

```
<div class="nbplayer"></div>
<div class="nbchat"></div>
<div class="nbpresentation"></div>
```

Thanks for any reply!

Comment: What do you mean by resize evenly? height? width?

Answer (score 0):

```
var $divs = $('.nbplayer, .nbchat, .nbpresentation');

$('#button').on('click', function() {
    $divs.css('width', $(window).width() / 3);
});
```

It may need some modifications to take margin/border/padding into account, if any.
(Or height if yours divs are placed vertically.)